# How to add custom rendering button to Renderings node

Tags: presentation

I have duplicated the `Controller rendering` template to create a custom rendering here - `/sitecore/templates/System/Layout/Renderings/`

Is it possible to add this as an insert option to the renderings node.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to go to this Sitecore Item and update the rule to add your custom rendering template.

```
/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Insert Options/Rules/MVC Renderings
```

[image]